# Add object to typescript model

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to create a model from a call to an api that returns objects in the response.

I have a simple `class` but now there is an object in the model and I don't know how to create my `class` as the `school->name` property in not defined on my page and typescript is complaining.

```
export class User {
  title: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  school : object {
  name: string
 }
}
```

What is the correct syntax to add the `school` object

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close - you just leave out the word "object". Like this:

```
export class User {
    title: string;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    school: {
        name: string
    }
}

// Sample usage
const user = new User();

user.school = { name: 'Beacon Hills High School' }
```

You can also create a User with an object literal:

```
const user: User = {
    title: 'Mr',
    first_name: 'Student',
    last_name: 'Rik',
    school: { name: 'Beacon Hills High School' }
};
```

Comment: When I did that it was still an error, I used 
```
school = {
    name: ''
  }
```

Comment: @StudentRik did you tried mine? and let me know what error exactly you are getting.

Comment: @StudentRik - are you trying to create a `User` using an object literal? If so, I have added a working example of that to the answer. If you intend to only define the structure, you may want to switch from `class` to `interface`.

Answer (score 1):

try this proper model creation  way

```
export class User {
    title: string;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    school: School;
}

export class School {
    name: string;
}

let user = new User();
let school = new School();
school.name = 'Beacon Hills High School';
user.school = school;
```